# parent form containing MenuStrip control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a simple desktop app that I've been building.  Currently it is using a bunch of buttons to navigate back and forth between forms.

Now I've decided to add a small MenuStrip control at the top to also help with navigation.

I currently have the same MenuStrip in every form with duplicate code like this:

```
Private Sub AddEngineToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddEngineToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim frmShowEnginesForm = New frmShowEnginesForm()
    frmShowEnginesForm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub EnterSpecsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterSpecsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim frmEnterEngineSpecsForm = New frmEnterEngineSpecsForm()
    frmEnterEngineSpecsForm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

I was hoping to simplify this a bit, so that if I ever want to add another menu item, I don't have to go through all my forms and change them all.

Is there a way to create a sort-of parent control/form that contains the MenuStrip so I don't have to duplicate it across all my forms?

THanks!

Comment: maybe add some `Sub` into `module` where You'll create `MenuStrip` in desired form...  but, You'll need to call that `sub`, for example `Public Sub CreateMenuStrip(frm As Form)....End Sub` adding handlers etc, from every `Form_Load`...

Comment: @nelek I'm not quite sure I follow.  Could you post an example answer?  thanks!

Comment: You could create a main form with the menu strip and a ToolStripContiner.  Then make your other forms Panels (UserControl) that you just doc in the container. (Actually, I think you can dock a form in a form, but it's been a while)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add new `module` to your project and use code bellow :

```
Module Module1

    Public Sub CreateMenuStrip(frm As Form)
        'create new MenuStrip control
        Dim ms As New MenuStrip
        ms.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        ms.Dock = DockStyle.Top

        'create new toolstripmenuitem
        Dim itm As New ToolStripMenuItem
        itm.Name = "miAddEngine"
        itm.Text = "Add Engine"
        'add handler what will happen when you click on this item... same for next item
        AddHandler itm.Click, AddressOf AddEngineToolStripMenuItem_Click
        ms.Items.Add(itm)

        itm = New ToolStripMenuItem
        itm.Name = "miEnterSpecs"
        itm.Text = "Enter Specs"
        AddHandler itm.Click, AddressOf EnterSpecsToolStripMenuItem_Click
        ms.Items.Add(itm)

        '...
        'there you can, latter, add new item and bellow sub add subs which will handle click or whatever
        '...

        'add control to the form
        frm.Controls.Add(ms)

    End Sub

    'subroutines which will handle Click
    Private Sub AddEngineToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox("open add engine form")
    End Sub

    Private Sub EnterSpecsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox("open enter specs form")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Now, from every your form(s), on load, call `CreateMenuStrip(Me)`

for example, in Form1 :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateMenuStrip(Me)
End Sub
```

Of course, You can always create `MDI Form` and his child's, putting that `MenuStrip` in the, for example, top of `MDIForm`.